# Facebook comments box on front page

Tags: plugins, comments, facebook, frontpage

I have a WordPress 3.5.1 installation on my [WordPress Shack](http://wordpress.camilstaps.nl), with the [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) 1.3.1 installed and the TwentyTwelve 1.1 theme. I have the settings on Facebook - Comments box so that I display the comments box on posts and pages. In Settings - Reading, I checked a static page as front page, "Welcome". I've checked the "Allow comments" checkbox for every page on my site.

However, the Facebook comments box is displayed on every page, except the front page, "Welcome".

This definitely is an issue with the front page, because if I select "latest posts" to display on the front page, the comments box is displayed on the Welcome page.

How can I make that the comments box is displayed on the front page as well?

<sub>I of course [posted this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/comments-on-static-front-page?replies=2) at the WordPress support forums for Facebook, but I don't get any response.</sub>

Comment: `print_r(get_option('facebook_home_features'));` - What do you get for that?

Comment: @tf it's an empty array.

Comment: Hm, okay, this should not be empty, if you selected 'home' for the Comments Box (or any other feature). What about the (regular) pages? `print_r(get_option('facebook_page_features'));`

Comment: @tf Ah, but when I select a like button for the homepage, there is an `array('like'=>1)`. However, I cannot select the homepage for the comments box, so I'll guess it's just not possible then. Is there a workaround possible?

Comment: Well, not a workaround, but let's say a _hack_. In the `facebook.php` file change line **319** to this: `if (is_home()) {`. That should have the effect that the front page is regarded as a regular page.

Comment: @tf you have done some awesome work, this solves the problem! Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Fast 'n' Hacky

The problem can be solved by changing line 319 in `facebook.php` to the following:

```
if (is_home()) {
```

This way, the front page is not treated as a *home* page but as a regular page, for which the facebook feature settings can be applied (and will be handled correctly).

---

#### More Elegant/Complex

Here is a *non-hackish* version. Put the following in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'force_facebook_comments');
function force_facebook_comments() {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        $features = get_option('facebook_home_features');
        $features['comments'] = true;
        update_option('facebook_home_features', $features);
        add_filter('comments_template', array('Facebook_Comments', 'comments_template'));
    }
    // If you want to handle the 'home' page differently, undo the above stuff
    // elseif (is_home()) {
        // $features = get_option('facebook_home_features');
        // $features['comments'] = false;
        // update_option('facebook_home_features', $features);
        // remove_filter('comments_template', array('Facebook_Comments', 'comments_template'));
    // }
}
```

Comment: @CamilStaps Okay then, I added a _not-hackish_ version. ;)

Comment: Thanks! But, you're talking about 'your `functions.php`' - where do I find that? Facebook doesn't have a functions.php, and I can't find one in the root folder either.

Comment: It's part of your theme. And if not, just add the file with only the above code wrapped in `<?php ... ?>` inside.

Comment: Ah, thanks! It works :) (and will keep working, even after a facebook update ;))

Comment: That's right. :) But maybe you want to get in touch with the author(s) and suggest to treat _home_ and _front-page_ differently, meaning insert a new option `facebook_front_page_features`, and also allow the user to select _front-page_ for comments.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I already opened a support question on WordPress (see the link in my question), but Facebook's developers support... well, don't get me started on that :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the plugin to test this, but looking at the lines to hack, as pointed by @tf:

```
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    $enabled_features = get_option( sprintf( $option_name, 'home' ) );
} else if ( is_archive() ) {
    // all archives wrapped in one option
    // is_post_type_archive || is_date || is_author || is_category || is_tag || is_tax
    $enabled_features = get_option( sprintf( $option_name, 'archive' ) );
} else {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ( $post_type )
        $enabled_features = get_option( sprintf( $option_name, $post_type ) );
}
```

I think it's possible to short-circuit the third option -`} else {`- using [`apply_filters( 'pre_option_' . $option, false );`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/option.php#L40).

Something like:

```
foreach( array( 'post', 'page' ) as $pt )
    add_filter( "pre_option_facebook_{$pt}_features", "callback" );

function callback()
{
    // let the option work normally
    if( !is_front_page() )
        return false;

    return get_option( 'facebook_home_features' );
}
```

Comment: I did not test this, however, nice to know the `pre_option_*` filter now. Didn't know that before. Then, two things: First, I guess it must be `pre_option_facebook_{$pt}_features` as the underscore is a valid character for variable names, so the parser will look for the variable `$pt_features`. Second, don't you want to `return get_option('facebook_page_features');`?

Comment: Yep, it was looking strange, corrected. As for the return, I'm not sure about the logic that has to be applied, it has to be adjusted accordingly. When I don't find a initial hook, I go after the functions involved, most of the times there's an entry point ;)

Comment: The problem is, the plugin only gives _post_, _page_ and _attachment_ as options to choose from when setting the comments. Thus, the option `*_home_*` does not contain the key `comments`, which is required here. And as Camil wants to treat the front page as a regular page, I chose to use the _page_  option. Anyway: +1. :)

Comment: I guess you took a deeper look at the plugin. Nice to see your *non hacking the (mini)core* solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) `front-page.php` or `home.php` will take precedence over the other pages.

After reviewing the code for the facebook plugin the options there appears to be a different set of options for these cases.

Comment: I'm using Twenty Twelve 1.1. It does not have a `front-page.php` or `home.php` template. Any ideas?

Comment: I added `comments_template('',true)` (from `single.php`) to `index.php` which most likely generates the front page. However, it's still displaying the same, wrong comments box.

Comment: I didn't look at the site until after I posted my answer.  I have revised my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure what you mean by that - what can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be theme related. I haven't used Twenty Twelve much, but is the homepage generated from the **Appearance > Widget** section?

There are a bunch of themes that generate the homepage content based on the corresponding widget. Look in there for a box called `Content Left` `Content Right`, `Homepage Content` or something like that.

This has tripped me up a few times.

You stated there is no `front-page.php` or `home.php`, but if I remember correctly there should be a `content-home.php` that is called from the `single.php` or `page.php`.

Comment: There is a post type for the front page, but I'm not using it. The front page is really just a page. Using it removes the default comments box, but doesn't show Facebook's comments box. There is no `content-home.php`.

Comment: Check out the support page for the plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-facebook-custom-post-type-support

Have you posted a thread there as well?

Comment: Irrelevant, I'm _not_ using a custom template. I posted this thread: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/comments-on-static-front-page

Comment: Ok, if all else fails, I would grab the code from the view source of one of the pages it's working on, and paste it manually in the page template.

something like this:
`if(is_front_page()){
*** paste code here ***
} `

Comment: Dang!! I type too slow.